# Magento SOAP API: How to get SOAP response using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, soap, ajax

I'm able to get SOAP response using Magento SOAP API by using PHP code. Now I want it using JavaScript/AJAX request.
How can I accomplish this? What steps should I follow prepare my Magento to allow AJAX http API request?
I tried with the following code for response:

```
$.soap({
      url: 'https://www.yourdomain.com/api/soap/?wsdl',
      method: 'login',

      data: {
          username:'xxxxx',
          apiKey:'xxxx'
      },

      success: function (soapResponse) {
          alert("yes!!");
      },
      error: function (SOAPResponse) {
          alert(SOAPResponse.toString());
      }
  });
```

I get this JavaScript error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.yourdomain.com/api/soap/?wsdllogin. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Comment: I think the basic question is: How do I send SOAP calls via JavaScript, right?
I found a nice answer on stackoverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11404133/865443

Comment: exactly! I already resolved it...thanks anyway

Comment: I don't know what's your application purpose or who will use it but you have a security issue doing this. If it's a web application accessible for everyone, they will all know your username and apiKey, they could try to get access to other data / create / modify ... of course it also depends on the role you've set on your API user.